# creating a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes `FOOTWEAR,APPAREL,ACCESSORIES` and each dataframe show the performance of 50 different suppliers showing their:

```
 sales,stock,markdown,purchases,changes in stock.
```

I want to create output that takes data  of each supplier from the 3 dataframes, combine it to one dataframe and export as an Excel. So the output should be 50 Excel tables with information of each supplier and their performance in all departments.

Comment: how to ask good questions in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  and welcome to stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

Let `df1`, `df2`, `df3` be your 3 dataframes (FOOTWEAR, APPAREL, ACCESSORIES). I have made subset with 5 rows from `mtcars` data.

```
df1<-subset(mtcars[1:5,])
df2<-subset(mtcars[6:10,])
df3<-subset(mtcars[11:15,])
```

Then the following loop could be used:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){

   assign(paste('r', i, sep = ''), 
          cbind(assign(paste('s', i, sep = ''), 
                       cbind(df1,df2)[i,]),df3)[i,])
 }
```

`r1` to `r50` will be your desired dataframes.